# how to detect touch event in table cells for iphone

Tags: iphone

how to detect touch event for table cells 
i tried this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //<my stuff>

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

but its not working actuallly i have aUIimage view in table cell and i want to chnage  imgae based on tap  so my touch event is not working for that cell

Answer (score 9):

If you want to detect a touch on the UITableViewCell you don't really need to detect touch events. In your UITableViewController subclass, you need to implement the following delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Then you modify the image of the table cell for the selected index path.

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to set `myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`.

Comment: yes both side i did .. my touch event is not at all working in table cells its just working outside of cells

Answer (score 2):

In one of my projects I needed any tap on the tableView to dismiss the keyboard so the underlying tableView would show.  Since a UITableView is really a UIScrollView, it will respond to the  scrollView delegate methods.  Using these 2 methods will dismiss if either the user taps on a cell or scrolls the tableView at all:

IMPORTANT: Make sure you implement the **UIScrollViewDelegate** in your .h file as well as the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSourceDelegate!!!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //remove keyboard if table row is clicked
    if ([self.firstName isFirstResponder] || [self.lastName isFirstResponder]) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        [self.firstName resignFirstResponder]; 
        [self.lastName resignFirstResponder]; 
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    //remove keyboard if table scrolls
    if ([self.firstName isFirstResponder] || [self.lastName isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.firstName resignFirstResponder]; 
        [self.lastName resignFirstResponder]; 
    }
}
```